# Proxy/firewall windows bypass?

Tags: windows-7, networking, security, proxy, windows-firewall

i am in with a little challenge here.

We have a network where the Computers connect to our domain, to log on, and get internet connection... This work as a wireless connection. My boss made a very limited account for me and setup some kind of proxy for so that we only were able to connect to our domain and webserver on localdomain. He then said that i should try to get pass the proxy thing and load up google or whatever website i wanted to if i managed to it. so it's basicaly a security test of our system.

I have until now found out that this is some kind of proxy that automaticly redirects me to our proxyserver on our domain-namespace. and if i go to our domain and try to load "google" on the webpage as an iframe or something it will get blocked. so i think that it's actually some kind of firewall rules on the computer/user. Wich does, when it tries use GET from a webserver that is blocked in the firewall rules on the computer/user, it redirects the GET command to the Error-page "Proxy-error (or something, i dont remember)" on our server, so that it loads the GET_content of our webserver instead.

And since the plan is to not get admin-privilegies with booting up linux and removing the firewall-rules (as i think is the blocking action here) from an external account. i want to try cheating the firewall somehow on the user where i have no admin-privilegies (maybe possible to get some?) and no access to any kind of control-panel stuff, exept from command promt and maybe powershell (but i am not admin)

Does someone have any idea on how i can get by this proxy or firewall thing, or write a small script and put it on a USB-stick to trick the rules?

And please correct me if this is off-topic!

Comment: see if it's browser only, try wget.  And another thing you can try, is try to ssh out.. easier said than done, if you haven't done it before. But set up an SSH server on your home machine or some unrestricted machine somewhere then SSH to that SSH server , ssh -D will help there.

Comment: Is it a [transparent proxy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proxy_server#Transparent_proxy) server or are the browsers on your computer configured to point to the proxy server? A transparent proxy server will likely be harder to bypass. [Check the Windows proxy server settings](http://support.moonpoint.com/network/proxy/settings/); if it is the latter you might be able to remove the proxy server settings on your system, but you still might be blocked by a firewall that only allows outbound 80 and 443 connections from the designated proxy server.

Comment: If you wish to try barlop's suggestion, there are a number of SSH server programs available for Windows systems; some companies will provide their commercial products for free for home use, e.g., [PowerShell Server for Windows](http://support.moonpoint.com/reviews/software/windows/network/ssh/PSSrvr6/) and [Bitvise SSH Server](http://www.bitvise.com/ssh-server). I've also used [CopSSH](http://support.moonpoint.com/reviews/software/windows/network/ssh/Copssh501/). Or you can fairly easily set up one on a Mac OS X or Linux system. You could then use it as a SOCKS proxy bypassing the work proxy.

Answer (score 1):

If this is being done at the network layer (access point, firewall, etc.), then it's very unlikely you will ever get around it. If it's done at the system (OS) level, and you aren't an admin, the odds are low you'll be able to get around it -- 'tho it depends on exactly how it's being done (read: how cheap is the nanny-software they're using.) If it's being forced on you at the application level (which is common for windows systems where everything is "IE"), it may be trivial to get around it if you can use other applications.